# Mongodb , rails modify non-array - debug kind_of? Array >> true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I've been trying to add to an array (or what ruby is saying is an array), but keep getting an error from mongo which says

```
Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array
```

when I try to run

```
 
 User.collection.update({'id'=> current.id},{'$addToSet'=>{ 'following' => current.id}})
    User.collection.update({'id'=> user.id},{'$addToSet'=>{ 'following' => user.id}})
```

or the mongomapper version

```
User.push_uniq(current.id, :following => user.id)
    User.push_uniq(user.id, :followers => current.id)
```

When I output

```
<%= debug @user.following.kind_of? Array %>
```

returns true

However, when running

```
db.users.find()
```

directly agains mongo, I get

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c4a196f15a79004e0000007"), "email" : "test@test.com", "foll
owers" : null, "following" : null, "password_hash" : "98f2188de42bce1554d08fbc81
d5c99a2c234933", "password_salt" : "25d80a83cfe3d126cdbe9fec2b731ab9ea57c3b8", "
username" : "test" }
```

I would have expected following and followers to be [], not null.

When I output debug @user.followers, rails shows --- []

My model to create the user is

```
  key   :username,      :type => String
  key   :email,         :type => String
  key   :password_hash, :type => String
  key   :password_salt, :type => String
  key   :followers,     :type => Array
  key   :following, :type => Array
```

The error leads me to believe that the user.followers is being found, but can't be updated.
When I change

```
 User.push_uniq(current.id, :testing => user.id)
```

I don't get an error, so I think i have that part right. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a potential bug in MongoMapper. I'd suggest posting this to the MM Google group. The field in the db needs to be an array to begin with, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

This works for be in 0.8 when declaring the key using `key :following, Array` instead of `key :following, :type => Array`.

I tried both `push_uniq` and `collection.update`, and didn't get errors on either one. In your `collection.update` example, you do need to use `_id: value` instead of `id: value` since that command is being passed to mongo directly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bit of an inconsistency with defining keys in mongomapper.

Don't use the :type => qualifier with Arrays.

I deleted the entire collection, removed :type, and recreated everything and now it works.